# Bootstrap button dropdown inside td, going on 2 lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got an issue with a **Bootstrap 3** button dropdown. You can see my 2 examples here:

http://www.bootply.com/W1dLusilMk

http://www.bootply.com/GGBvggjYmu

The 1st one has only a short value in the first **td**, which means the last one doesn't get squished. However, if you look at the 2nd example, that content is *much* wider.

On a desktop, this isn't so much of an issue. However, if you look at it on the mobile version (little icon on that page), you can see that the 2nd example breaks. The select box splits into 2, and the caret goes onto the 2nd line

Now - some background. The page this goes on is responsive. The table these buttons go in are also responsive. The content within the select boxes also changes (as they can be different room types), so a fixed width there isn't a solution.

At first, I though I could wrap a div around the button, with some kinda CSS that would "force" it to stay on one line - but I've come up with nothing.

**FWIW:** I've also tried `nowrap` and `white-space:nowrap;` on the cell that holds the dropdown - but no such luck it would seem :/

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Works ok with this, for example:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>foo bar</td>
      <td>
          <div class="btn-group dropdown-m-wrapper" rel="1400::245::1">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default toggle-drop" rel="1400::245::1" id="select_1400_245_1">Choisir chambre</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="1400::245::1" class="change-room-selected-status" data-value="2"><b class="fa fa-user"></b> €1400</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>      
      </td>

    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

...but not:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo barfoo bar foo bar foo bar foo barfoo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar</td>
      <td>
          <div class="btn-group dropdown-m-wrapper" rel="1400::245::1">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default toggle-drop" rel="1400::245::1" id="select_1400_245_1">Choisir chambre</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="1400::245::1" class="change-room-selected-status" data-value="2"><b class="fa fa-user"></b> €1400</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>      
      </td>

    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: set a width to the td containing the dropdown

Comment: @NoobEditor - what have I done wrong? I gave 2 examples, and a description of my problem! (as well as what I've tried)

Comment: @LucaRasconi - thats not really an option (as I explained). We have varying widths (depending on the content in the select boxes), and the table cell needs to be flexible to fit that :(

Comment: @AndrewNewby : thats more like it!!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor - I already gave all the example code in the links, so didn't think it was worth wasting the space in the post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the with of the td cause the caret don't go onto second line.
The select is not fixed, insted it should be left shift. 
Try this: http://www.bootply.com/mutJgilNS8 
or see bootstrap examples http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-examples

Comment: Thanks. I was kinda trying to avoid fixed widths / min-width, but it looks thats gonna have to be how we do it :( I did a bit of a tweak with a **max-width** so that it changes the min-width based on the view size - but it seems to have done the trick :)